# UITableview background changes while searching

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

i am developing an app contains an UITableView and a search bar. I set clear color to the background of the the UITableView, but while i am searching an item in the search bar the TableView background color turns to white. How can i avoid this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the same background to the view where's the tableview too.

Hope it helps, **Mário**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that once you start searching, searchbar has its own tableview which it uses to display the search results. I'm not sure of any way to get a handle to that tableview so that the color can be changed.